# Custom 404 error without server

Tags: html, browser

Is possible to intercept 404 error without using web server (browsing html file in the filesystem) ?

I tried with some javascript, using an hidden iframe that preload the destination page and check for the result and then trigger a custom error or redirect to the correct page.

This work fine but is not good on perfomance.

Comment: Your title & question do not match.

Comment: Sorry  I was lostinthought...

Comment: It happens. I just pointed it out since it was a bit confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A 404 error is an HTTP status response. So unless you are trying to retrieve this file using an HTTP request/response, you can't have a genuine 404 error. You can only mimic one in something like the way you suggest. Any "standard" way of handling a 404 error is dependent on your flavour of web server anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you want to use the server?

I don't believe that it's possible to handle a 404 error client-side, because a 404 error is *server-side*.

Whenever you load a webpage, you make a request to the server. Thus, when you ask for a file that's not there, it's the server that handles the error. Regular HTML/CSS/JavaScript only come into the picture when the server sends back a response to tell you that it can't find the file.

Steve

Answer (score 1):

404 is a HTTP response code, and as such only delivered through the HTTP protocol by servers that speak it. The file:// extension isn't a real protocol response as such, it's a hack built into clients (like browsers) that enable local file support, however it's up to browsers / clients themselves whether they expose any response codes from their file:// implementation. In theory they could report them in the DOM, for example, but they would be response codes exposed to themselves, and as such rarely implemented. Most don't, and there isn't a standard way for it. You may look into browser extensions, like Firefox, and see if they support it, but then, this is highly unstandard and will likely break if you pop it on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Because I was looking for this today. You can now do this without a server by using a Service Worker to cache the custom 404 page, and then serve it when a fetch request status is 404. Following the instructions on the [google cache lab](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/lab-caching-files-with-service-worker#5_optional_respond_with_custom_404_page), the worker files looks as follows:

```js
const filesToCache = [
  '/',
  '404.html'
];

const staticCacheName = 'pages-cache-v1';

self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  console.log('Attempting to install service worker and cache static assets');

  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(staticCacheName).then(cache => {
      return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
    });
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  console.log('Fetch event for ', event.request.url);

  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request).then(response => {
      if (response) {
        console.log('Found ', event.request.url, ' in cache');
        return response;
      }
    
      console.log('Network request for ', event.request.url);
      
      return fetch(event.request).then(response => {
        console.log('response.status:', response.status);

        // fetch request returned 404, serve custom 404 page
        if (response.status === 404) {
          return caches.match('404.html');
        }
      });
    });
  );
});
```